# How to convert a delimited string of hex numbers to an int array

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, array

I am sending a string to the Arduino via serial, I made the program that sends the data, so I can change it to anything, but for now it sends a string of hex numbers delimited by ':', so for example 00:AA:FF and I need to get that into an int array onto the Arduino, the main problem is I don't always know how big the array will be, sometimes just 2 indexes, other times 16 indexes.

As I said, I made the program sending the data so I can make the data anything, I just need to get an int array to the Arduino and get it back as an int array via serial

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: Do you know an upper limit on how many there will be?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the hex numbers in a `int array` using [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and [strtol()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).

```
char str[] = "00:AA:FF:7FFF";
int intArray[16]; // Maximum number of hex numbers.

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  int counter = 0;
  char * pch = strtok(str, ":");

  while(pch != NULL){
    intArray[counter] = strtol(pch, NULL, 16);
    pch = strtok(NULL, ":");
    counter++;
  }
  Serial.print("Item Count = ");
  Serial.println(counter);

  for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
    Serial.println(intArray[i]);
  }

}

void loop(){}
```